# Why does the margin here animate before the previous keyframe ends?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

As you can see in this demo I made:

https://jsfiddle.net/wd0um6q9/1/

Margin begins to animate immediately. However, it's not defined until the 3rd keyframe. So I would expect the animation for it to start once the 2nd keyframe values are finished animating. That doesn't seem to be the case and I'm trying to understand why.

I noticed that if I manually set the margin in the 2nd keyframe, it will work as expected, but it seems odd to me that I would have to define it there since it's already set outside of the keyframe.

```
.test {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  animation: fadeOut 6s cubic-bezier(0,.27,.39,1) 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: .5;
    max-height: 400px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are correct in that you would think it would pickup the initial value.

The animation that you are building needs a start and an end.

Adding it in at the 30% mark, gives the margin its starting value, and the 100% mark will kick start its animation.

The below should give you the effect you are looking for, while trimming some unneeded values

```
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    width:400px;
    margin: 50px 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: .5;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 50px 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: red;
    margin:0;
  }
}
```